# Multiple choice questions with autofill answers table

Tags: exam

I have a question on how to make multiple choice questions and then generate a table with correct answers for grading. For example:

1) What's the result of 2X4:

A. 8

B. 6

C. 4

D. None of the above

2) What's the result of 2/4:

A. 2

B. 4

C. 6

D. 0.5

Then when I compile this exam, I get a table *on a separate sheet* with the correct answers like this:

[image]

Please help me as I am new with Latex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are specific document classes for that like `exam`. However, until you make your question more concrete by adding a concrete LaTeX document you may not necessarily get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will let you write your questions as:

```
\begin{questions}
  \item What's the result of $2\times 4$:
    \begin{choices}
      \item* 8
      \item 6
      \item 4
      \item None of the above
    \end{choices}
  \item What's the result of $\tfrac{2}{4}$:
    \begin{choices}
      \item 2
      \item 4
      \item 6
      \item* 0.5
    \end{choices}
\end{questions}
```

Use `\item*` for the correct choices - you can, if you want, have more than one correct choice for each question. The output is:

[image]

The "answer table" is as requested, although I probably would not do it  this way. The different questions can have a different number of choices but the answer table will be missing a few cells in that case.

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% save \item so we can override it in the choices environment
\let\real_item\item
\int_new:N \g_question_int
\int_new:N \g_max_choices_int
\NewDocumentCommand\start_choices{}{
  \let\item\choices_item
  \seq_new:c {g_choices\arabic{questionsi}_seq}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\choices_item{s}{
  \real_item
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    { \seq_gput_right:cx {g_choices\arabic{questionsi}_seq} {*\arabic{choicesi}} }
    { \seq_gput_right:cx {g_choices\arabic{questionsi}_seq} { \arabic{choicesi}} }
  % now update the maximum number of columns
  \int_compare:xNVT {\arabic{choicesi}} > \g_max_choices_int {
       \int_gset:Nn \g_max_choices_int {\arabic{choicesi}}
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\print_answer{ sm } {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbf{\int_to_Alph:n {#2}}}{\int_to_Alph:n {#2}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\print_answers{}{
  \int_compare:VNnT \g_max_choices_int > {0} {
    \newpage
    \int_set:Nn \g_question_int {0}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|*{\int_use:N \g_max_choices_int}{c|}}\hline
    \int_while_do:nn { \g_question_int < \arabic{questionsi} } {
      \int_gadd:Nn \g_question_int {1}
      \int_use:N \g_question_int.
      \seq_map_inline:cn {g_choices \int_use:N \g_question_int _seq} {&\print_answer##1}
      \\\hline
    }
    \end{tabular}
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_compare:nNnT {xNVT}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_compare:nNnT {VNnT}
% define enumitem environments for questions and choices
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[questions]{
   label=\bfseries\arabic*.,
   after=\print_answers
}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{
   label=\Alph*).,
   before=\start_choices,
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \item What's the result of $2\times 4$:
    \begin{choices}
      \item* 8
      \item 6
      \item 4
      \item None of the above
    \end{choices}
  \item What's the result of $\tfrac{2}{4}$:
    \begin{choices}
      \item 2
      \item 4
      \item 6
      \item* 0.5
    \end{choices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

If you plan on using this then I'd recommend putting the code from the preamble in a style file, say `choices.sty`, and then loading it with `\usepackage{choices}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look to the `esami` package, which produces the string of correct choices for multiple choice questions (although they are not contained in a table as yours) or at the `acrotex` package by D.P. Story, on which the previous one is based. `acrotex` produces the table of correct choices as you want it.

Edit: the `esami` package has a structure wich does not allow a MWE to be posted here (two files are needed, at least: the master file and the exercises file). You can have a look to the example files which are included in the doc folder of the package.

Comment: Could you extend your answer to provide a small example document showing how this could be done using one of those packages?

Comment: In addition to siracusa's comment, this is just to inform you that please do not retag the question to fit the answer. `esami` maybe a solution to the problem, but the problem is not an `esami` problem.